# Vuejs select option inside blade.php view

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-blade

I am trying to built a simple select box and post the picked item later.
In my blade file I have following but the output is wrong.

```
<div class="input-field col s12 blue-text text-lighten-3">
    <select name="publish_status" v-model="publishStatus">
        <option value="0">Not publish</option>
        <option value="1">Yes publish</option>
    </select>
    <label>Publish status</label>
    <span>Selected: @{{ publishStatus }}</span>
</div>
```

This is the output of my span tag inside my browser view not the console

> Selected: {{ publishStatus }}

My vue instance:

```
new Vue({


    el: '#snippet-form',

    data: {
        publishStatus: '',

});
```

Comment: are you sure using `snippet-form` id in a tag wrapping your form?

Comment: @Mohd_PH yes I do

Comment: does other things in Vue work fine? it might not be included in your `app.js` file

Comment: @Mohd_PH the other functions work ist included

Comment: Could you please tell us the solution when you find it? we would love to know

Answer (score 0):

where is the element id#snippet-form? I have just created a working fiddle based on your code here: https://jsfiddle.net/farazshuja/oguLapf7/1/

html:

```
<div id="snippet-form" class="input-field col s12 blue-text text-lighten-3">
...
</div>
```

Comment: have u added the id="snippet-form"?

Comment: yes the html Markup is inside a div with th eid snippet-form, I also do not get an error shown in my dev console